# How can i set title for MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, title

In my application i want to set the title for the video (At the time of video playing).  How do I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by title? Some label you want to set it's text property to the name of the video?

Answer (score 0):

You can try placing a `UILabel` over the movie player's view